# Can I apply a Group Policy only to systems that have specific software installed?

Tags: group-policy, wmi

If I wanted to setup a group policy that installed Java, this would be no problem. But is it possible for the group policy to only apply to systems that have Mozilla Firefox installed?
I don't know much about WMI, but I imagine if it can be done, it would be with a WMI filter?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering your question: yes it is possible with WMI filter.

from a nice blog on technet with examples:

example WMI:

> Select * from Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms where displayname = "nvidia
>   drivers" AND version = "1.10"

source:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/18/group-policy-filtering-of-installed-applications.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I was simply asking if this was possible, and he answered it. Then he provided a link for reference. I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: This WMI query seems to require that the WMI Windows Installer Provider is installed on the processing computer or you get error `0x80041010`. http://clintboessen.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/wmi-error-invalid-class-0x80041010-fix.html